# Accessing environment variables with the same name than bash variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

This outputs 1:

```
A=1; A=2 echo $A
```

While this outputs 2:

```
A=1; A=2 python2 -c 'import os; print os.environ["A"]'
```

In bash, is there any way to read the environment variable instead of the bash variable without writing helper code (python, perl, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

```
A=1 ; A=2 bash -c 'echo $A'
A=1 ; A=2 eval 'echo $A'
A=1 ; A=2 eval echo '$A'
A=1 ; ( export A=2 ; echo $A )
A=1 ; ( A=2 ; echo $A )
function echoVar () { printf '%s\n' "${!1}" ; } ; A=1 ; A=2 echoVar A
```